# Notification bar key-binding?

Tags: notification-bar, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a bluetooth keyboard that I've set up in such a way that I can essentially use every function on my phone using just they keyboard, with home and menu and arrow keys and such. The only *major* thing I still can't do is look at my notifications! I have to reach up to pull the bar down, and I can't find a key binding to just pull the notification bar down. Does anyone know of one?

In other words, is there a command in the format:
`key ###    NOTIFICATION_PULL          WAKE_DROPPED`

or does someone know of another way I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround at least while in the main launcher home screen is to press MENU and then NOTIFICATIONS.

Else get [HelloStatusBar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.androdev.hellostatusbar) and assign it to a shortcut key. You can also try [Status bar Expander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.friedflow.statusbarexpander) which uses a long-press on the menu key to drop the bar wherever you are.

Naturally, YMMV as certain devices don't support these apps.

Comment: unfortunately, ADW launcher doesn't have that option, and Status bar Expander works with a long press of the *search* button, which I like to use for Voice Search :/ Trying HelloStatusBar now though!

Comment: and now I'm getting `Error Processing Purchase` on HelloStatusBar :(

Comment: [Status Bar Expander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.friedflow.statusbarexpander) is a little classier, and the app acts the same as [HelloStatusBar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.androdev.hellostatusbar) in that I can map it to a key-combo shortcut. Two buttons rather than one, but better than none! Thanks @Sparx !!

Answer (score 3):

In Android 6 (aka Android M and Android Marshmallow), Win+N works.

Comment: Working all the way to Android 12, you rock big boss